# SQL Server 2017 Express Installation fails

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2017 Express on Windows 10 and it is failing.

Here is the details it shows me after failure:

```
Action required:
Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Feature failure reason:
An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.

Error details:
§ Error installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
VS Shell installation has failed with exit code 1638.
Error code: 1638
Log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171018_083459\VCRuntime140_x64_Cpu64_1.log
Visithttps://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=VCRuntime140_x64%40Install%400x1638 to get help on troubleshooting.
```

I am Windows 10 and have Visual Studio 2017 installed.
I'm thinking the problem could be I installed SQL Server Management Studio 2017 before I installed SQL Server.

I have the same setup at home but I installed SQL Server first and then SSMS and everything works fine.

The other difference is at home in the installation dialog it says something the affect that C++ Redistribuble is already installed but at  work where it is failing it says it is to be installed in hte list of components.

Comment: From copy and pasting the error, I got this really easy, hope it helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3c15e264-026c-4a44-af90-13c870ee4d2f/install-error-installing-microsoft-visual-c-2015-redistributable?forum=SQLServer2016Preview

Answer (score 29):

The problem is likely that there's a newer version of the Visual C++ Redistributable than SQL Server is trying to install, e.g., from Visual Studio 2017. So another way to address this, if you don't need the latest C++ redistributable, is to go to Add or Remove Programs and uninstall all references to Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable. After this, the SQL Server installation should proceed without errors.

Comment: Thank you Luc, this helped me.

Comment: Thank you, this also worked for me.  What a pain!  I installed VS 2017 before SQL Server 2017 install and this fixed it.  thanks

Answer (score 11):

I had this error before all I did was(using Win10 x64):

Go to **control panel**-> Select **Programs** -> **Programs and Features** -> Search "**c++**"
-> In the list select **Visual C++ 2017**(or your version error) **Redistributable** -> right click select "**change**" -> select **repair**.

After that I was able to continue and successfully installed SQL Server Express 2017.

**Note:** 
Some requires uninstall and reinstall again therefore if the above procedure doesn't work just try reinstalling it.

Comment: It helped me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My instance of SQL Server wanted Visual C++ Redistributable 2017, but when I tried to install it, I was told there was a newer version already installed, which was odd because each version of the Redistributable is unique. You target a specific version in your code and may need several versions installed side-by-side. I followed the above instructions and discovered I had a single package installed for all versions from 2015-2019. Once I repaired this package, I was able to repair install SQL Server

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out for my environment.
If you have Visual Studio 2017, go back into the installer and install the "ATL C++" workload.  Now when you go through the SQL Server 2017 install it will say C++ already installed and the installation will be successful.

Comment: Sql Server 2017 isn't compatible with VS 2017. The stupidity of MS never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution :

1. remove `VC++ 2017`.
2. download `VC++ 2015` from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1)
3. install `VC++ 2015`
4. install `SQL Server 2017`
5. install `SSMS 2017`

Comment: Thanks only thing that worked. Microsoft should up their error description game

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I just repair the program **Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) - 14.16.27029** from `Add Remove Program` and setup run without any error.

Answer (score 1):

I also found running the repair of the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable corrected the issue and was able to install SQL 2017 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 23 KB5000685

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the following from Programme and Features option fixed my issue.

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
```

MSSQL 2017 installation will automatically add it once the installation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you haven't installed SSMS before, 
First install SQLSERVER then SSMS.
To resolve this error just uninstall MS visual C++ Redistributable v13/v15/v17 as they get installed already when you install SSMS before.
Run the setup again it will continue installation.