# How to solve SQL Server Express installation error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-express

While installing SQL Server express 2017 in windows, getting the following error:

[image]

Please any one suggest to move forward on installation

Comment: The error says "Invalid command line argument" - what command line are you using?

Comment: Error -2068052377 and "Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help" are a generic error from the Windows Installer components. Step 1: Examine the log files in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190913_094622\`. Step 2: Resolve the issues uncovered in the log files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810525/sql-server-2017-express-installation-fails